# Having trouble with HTML build it margins

Tags: html, css

I’ve tried to build this top nav menu and it keeps having some build in margin I know it’s not my code since I never added margins. here is the code.

```
<body class="body">
    <div id="div01">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://forexstat.co.uk/h/fhdfs">TEST</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://forexstat.co.uk/h/fhdfs">TEST 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://forexstat.co.uk/h/fhdfs">TEST 3</a></li>
            <div id="div02">
                <li><a href="https://forexstat.co.uk/h/fhdfs">TEST 3</a></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="div03">
```

And the CSS https://pastebin.com/XSW846vJ My first idea was to just add `div#div01 body {margin: -10px;}` to my CSS file so it just disappears but it doesn't seem to work the only way I can get it to remove the margins is by adding the `margin:-10px;` to my body file but then the hole WebPage is going to be broken I've tried putting `margin: -10;` in the CSS tags but it either dint do anything or it just deleted the padding on the Nav menu here is image of the Nav menu so you can understand where I'm coming from with the margin problem.

[image].
[image]

Comment: add `margin:0` on `body`

Comment: Thanks  that helped somewhat but i still have the problem with the top margins and paddding http://prntscr.com/scdl0t

Comment: Advice: Don't use `id` for styling, that is, don't use `#xyz { }` selectors.

Comment: @connexo Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul` tag has default `margin top bottom` 16px, and padding-left: 40px, you can set them to 0

```
#div01 ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding-left:0;
}
```

If you want to remove all margin, you can set `body{ margin:0;}` to remove default 8px `margin` at body.

```css
div#div01 a
{
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
div#div01 li
{
  float: left;
}
div#div01 ul
{
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
}
div#div01 a:hover
{
 background-color: #444444;
}
div#div02 li
{
  float: right;
}

#div01 ul{
margin: 0;
padding-left:0;
}
```

```html
<body class="body">
    <div id="div01">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://forexstat.co.uk/h/fhdfs">TEST</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://forexstat.co.uk/h/fhdfs">TEST 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://forexstat.co.uk/h/fhdfs">TEST 3</a></li>
            <div id="div02">
                <li><a href="https://forexstat.co.uk/h/fhdfs">TEST 3</a></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="div03">
```

Comment: what a about the padding on the left side how do I remove that one?

Comment: You can set padding left to 0, body margin to 0 you can copy my answer